# How do I aggregate over ordered subsets of rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table `t` filled like this:

```
x y z 
- - - 
A 1 A 
A 4 A 
A 6 B 
A 7 A 
B 1 A 
B 2 A
```

Basically, columns x and z are random letters and y random numbers.

I want to aggregate the rows as follows:

```
x z min(y) max(y)
- - ------ ------
A A 1      4
A B 6      6
A A 7      7
B A 1      2
```

In other words: Given that the rows are ordered by x, y, and z, select the minimum and maximum y for each *consecutive* group of x and z.

Note that this query is not what I need:

```
select x, z, min(y), max(y)
from t
group by x, z
```

As this would result in the following unwanted result:

```
x z min(y) max(y)
- - ------ ------
A A 1      7
A B 6      6
B A 1      2
```

So the question is: is there a way to express what I want in SQL?

(In case the solution depends on the SQL dialect: an Oracle solution would be preferred.)

Comment: I think `B A 1      1` is an unwanted row(following your specifications).

Comment: Good catch, sorry about that!

Comment: You might be able to achieve it using [Analytic Functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a solution, but I don't have the time to explain it step by step:

```
select x, z, min(y), max(y)
from (
  select b.* , sum(switch) over (order by rn) as grp_new 
  from(
    select a.* , 
           case when grp = (lag(grp) over (order by rn))
           then 0 
           else 1 end as switch
    from 
        (select x,y,z, 
                dense_rank() over (order by x, z) as grp,
                row_number() over (order by x, y, z) rn
         from t
    )a
  )b
)c
group by x, z, grp_new
order by grp_new
```

[SQLFIDDLE to test it.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17790)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention Oracle version if your version supports [WITH](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php) and [ROW_NUMBER() OVER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

```
WITH C as
(
select t.*,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by x,y,z ) as rn
from t
), C2 as 

(
select t1.*,
( 
  select count(*) from c where Rn<=t1.Rn 
                               and (z<>t1.z or x<>t1.x) 
) as Grp
from c t1
) 

select x,z,min(y),max(y) from c2 
group by x,z,grp
order by min(rn)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03ad8/28)

Comment: Window functions (aka "analytical" functions) have been available since Oracle 8.2 and common table expressions since 9.1 I think

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select x, z, min(y), max(y)
  from (select x, z, y from t order by x, z))
 group by x, z
```

Comment: This outputs the same unwanted result in OP's post.

Comment: Do not understand what you say